# Select Multiple Columns join SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot

I have an `Employee` table like this

[image]

And a second table for `EmployeeComments` with the `EmployeeID` as foreign key:

[image]

I would like to query the employees with their comments in the following format:

```
select Name, Comment 
from Employee emp 
left join EmployeeComments empC on empC.EmployeeID = emp.ID
```

I would like the results to be like:

[image]

I have already looked at Pivot, but it doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: the case when row_number() over(partition by emp.name order by empC.ID) = 1  fixed my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window function:

```
select case when row_number() over(partition by emp.name order by empC.ID) = 1 
            then Name
            else '' end as Name, 
       Comment 
from Employee emp 
left join EmployeeComments empC On empC.EmployeeID = emp.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some kind of order in your result window at least

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT  emp.Name ,
            empC.Comment,
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY emp.Name) NameOrder,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.Name ORDER BY empC.ID) RN
    FROM    Employee emp
            LEFT JOIN EmployeeComments empC ON empC.EmployeeID = emp.ID
)
SELECT
    Name = (CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Name ELSE '' END),
    Comment
FROM 
    cte
ORDER BY 
    NameOrder,
    RN
```

Answer (score 0):

"use Cross Join:"

> Query:

```
  select case t.cnt
  when  1 then
  coalesce(t.Name,' ') 
  end as Name,t.comment
  from 
  (
  select t1.Name,t2.comment,row_number()
  over(partition by t1.name order by t1.Name) 
  as cnt
  from
  EmployeeComments t1 
  cross join 
  Employee t2
  where t1.ID=t2.Employeeid
  )t
```